# strange results with grep regular expression when used with pipe

Tags: command-line, grep, regex, pipe

I have 3 files: test1,test2,test3.sh. File test3.sh has names of files test1 and test2 as its contents. I am unable to understand the result the output of the below command:

```
sh-4.3$ touch test1 test2                                                                                                                                                       
sh-4.3$ ls                                                                                                                                                                      
main.sh  test1 test2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
sh-4.3$ cat > test3.sh                                                                                                                                                          
test1                                                                                                                                                                           
test2                                                                                                                                                                           
sh-4.3$ cat test3.sh                                                                                                                                                            
test1                                                                                                                                                                           
test2                                                                                                                                                                           
sh-4.3$ ls                                                                                                                                                                      
main.sh  test1  test2  test3.sh                                                                                                                                                 
sh-4.3$ ls | grep test*  

test3.sh:test1
```

the above grep command gives the matching text in test3.sh file, but what about the output of the ls command as it also contains the word "test". Is the shell ignoring the output of ls command while doing pattern searching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell expands your `*` to all matching files in the current directory before `grep` sees it, so the command after expansion is

```
grep test1 test2 test3.sh
```

`grep` interprets the first argument `test1` as the pattern to search for and the other arguments as the names of files to look in. The output from `ls` is passed as text on `grep`'s STDIN and not as filenames, and it seems that this is ignored, since it doesn't make sense in `grep`'s syntax after the expansion has been carried out.

Always quote your regex

```
$ ls | grep 'test*'
test1
test2
test3.sh
```

Comment: i got your answer, but what about the output coming from the ls command, does the grep command ignores it and doesn't perform pattern searching on the input from the pipe

Comment: thnks for the answer @Zanna